# How to set the size of an inner control of a user control dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have made a user control, containing 2 simple controls in it: A checkbox and a combobox. (and some copies of it that contain a checkbox and a textbox, or a checkbox and an IBAN control vs...)

When I use this user control in designer mode, changing the size of user control does not change the size of the inner controls naturally. I have to set the sizes of them in the page that I use the user control in the actual class but designer class. My aim is to let the width of those controls to be changed only by changing the width of the user control. What  I mean is:

Let's call our control `ucControl`, and its inner controls `cbCheckBox` and cmbComboBox. When I create this user control, I set a static size to all of those controls, and except the size of `ucControl`, sizes of the rest are not available for size changing from designer.

I want the size of the `cmbComboBox` to change when the size of the `ucControl` changes, according to a formula like:

`cmbComboBox.Size = new Size(ucControl.Size.Width - cbCheckBox.Size.Width - 15, 20)`

How and where should I do it?

What I tried so far:

I tried to use `SizeChanged` event but it didn't work. (It did not let me to create a void returning event method in the user control, no idea why.)

I tried to set it in the `load` method, it didn't work.

I tried to set it in the `InitializeComponent` method in the design class, it didn't work.

Comment: Anchor those child controls.

Comment: It works in the designer of the user control but not in the form that I use that user control.

Comment: Forget anchors .. use containers :)

Comment: When you anchor controls, you need to remove all of your resizing code, since it would interfere with the layout engine.  Otherwise, it's hard to know what you are doing that would make anchoring not work.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this is to use containers and make the control Dock with the Fill option. This way it will resize dynamically for you. You could also anchor it to left and right but I find container to be much more elegant option. The sample below uses a simple TableLayoutPanel with some rows and columns fixed.

[image]

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 120F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label2, 0, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label1, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1, 1, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 3;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 26F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 26F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(412, 198);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(62, 3);
        this.label1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 20);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "Checkbox";
        // 
        // checkBox1
        // 
        this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
        this.checkBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
        this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(123, 3);
        this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
        this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 20);
        this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.checkBox1.Text = "checkBox1";
        this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(71, 29);
        this.label2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 20);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.label2.Text = "TextBox";
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(123, 29);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(286, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(412, 198);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply anchoring the ComboBox to the Left and Right should achieve what you want.

Here is the UserControl right after the ComboBox was added to it:

[image: ComboBox in the UserControl]

Select the ComboBox and drag its Right Edge until it is your desired distance from the Right Edge of the UserControl:

[image: ComboBox resized so that it fills the width of the UserControl]

Change the Anchor Property of the ComboBox and turn on the Right Anchor so that you have both the Left and the Right turned on:

[image: ComboBox with Left and Right Anchor turned on]

Now try resizing the UserControl and see what happens to the ComboBox.

Comment: It works when I resize the user control in the designer of the user control itself but not in the form that I use it.

Comment: Most likely then, you do not have the UserControl itself setup in such a way that it gets resized with the Form.  It also needs to be either Docked or Anchored so that it gets resized (or some other container in your Form needs to be configured as well).